# use values and select from in the same insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use 'select from' and 'values' in the same insert but I'm getting an error:

```
with insert_user as(
 insert into users (user_name) values ('omni')
 returning *
),
insert_articles as( 
 insert into articles (article_text, user_id)
 values ('article text')
 select insert_users.id
 from insert_users
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a second CTE for the insert. Just put it in an outer query and it should work:

```
with insert_user as(
 insert into users (user_name) values ('omni')
 returning *
)
insert into articles (article_text, user_id)
select 'article text',insert_user.id 
from insert_user;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7a3ee823aa3ece3318e4572efc8d243e)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
postgres=# WITH insert_user as (
  INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES ('omni') RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO articles (article_text, user_id) SELECT 'article_text', id FROM insert_user;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from articles;
 article_text | user_id 
--------------+---------
 article_text |       1
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from users;   
 user_name | id 
-----------+----
 omni      |  1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

For combine VALUES and SELECT use [JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) or [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-union.html)